# Remote Linux node trying to access contents of a shared network drive

Tags: linux, network-drive

I have with me a shared network drive containing a set of jar's - for example latest eclipse plugins. I need to put them on a remote linux machine. What protocols can i use to perform these activities? The network drive and the linux machines are in different networks. What protocol would best suit this approach? I am not a computer geek so kindly request to provide me with simple to understand answers. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: rsync, sftp, ftp, samba, nfs. You should probably do some research here since none of us knows how your network is set up, or what kind of hoops you'll have to jump through to connect the two machines, or what is installed on either machine, or a bunch of other variables that could impact your ability to move files around between the two machines.

Comment: Hi, yeah that is ok. I was just wondering what are the most commonly used protocols that people would use to establish this exchange.

Comment: Yes. All of those. SFTP, nfs, the rsync command (over ssh), and ftp are extremely common. I'm not trying to be purposely obtuse, it's just that your question lacks in details and is overly broad. You say you have "With me a shared network drive" what does that mean? You have a hard drive in your pocket? You have a samba share drive on a windows machine? You have an NFS exported directory on a linux machine? Why not attach this "Shared drive" to your linux machine? What protocol is the shared drive? How can you connect into your other network? Is there a firewall? Port routing needs? ...

Answer (score 0):

Well as you mentioned your both machines are not in same network ? if you want to upload file to remote drive they must be in network  so they can talk with each other, for any type of remote file handling  `ftp` seems to be a good protocol.